# Will any 32 bit app run in 64 bit OSX 10.7 (Lion) Server

Tags: macos

I recently acquired a new Mac mini that has 64 bit OSX 10.7 Lion Server installed. I have a 32 bit app that will not run properly. I am wondering will OSX 10.7 Lion Server run 32 bit apps under a 64 bit kernel?

Comment: What application?

Comment: It's client specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general all apps that are built for 32 bit will run properly on OS X whether or not the kernel is booted in 64 bit mode or not.

The notable exceptions are:

- Linking to a library that is 32 bit only or missing and that library really doesn't run in 64 bit (it's rare, but can happen)
- Kernel extensions and other code that is tightly bound to the hardware or the OS

Feel free to edit the question into specifics or ask a follow on question listing the error you are getting and more details about the program to the extent you wish to share those details.